# Bind accepts only local connections

Tags: centos, bind

I am trying to fix the Bind (named) on CentOS server which only accepts connections from localhost.

My server has local IP 192.168.2.2 and dig works if I run it on same sever where named is installed. But dig executed on backup server which has IP 192.168.2.22 doesn't work.

```
dig @192.168.2.2 www.mydomain.com # works locally but not on backup server
```

Both servers are connected to same switch so there are no limits in between. This worked until yesterday when USB key was connected to the server and two module were installed using yum:
libmcrypt-2.5.8-4.el5.centos.x86_64 and php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.x86_64. In /var/log/messages I see some logs that I am not familiar with:

```
Mar 21 18:34:06 centos hald: mounted /dev/sdc1 on behalf of uid 0
Mar 21 18:38:55 centos kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Mar 21 18:38:55 centos kernel: Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
Mar 21 18:38:55 centos kernel: ip_conntrack version 2.4 (8192 buckets, 65536 max) - 304 bytes per conntrack
Mar 21 18:38:55 centos kernel: ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Mar 21 18:38:55 centos kernel: ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Mar 21 18:43:08 centos kernel: Removing netfilter NETLINK layer.
Mar 21 18:43:08 centos kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
```

I enabled debug logging in Bind but when I try to query it from backup server there is no sign of connection.

This is the netstat -a output:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.2:53              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53                  0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 192.168.2.2:53              0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*
```

And part of named.conf

```
options {
    directory "/var/named";
    query-source address * port 53;
};

controls {
    inet * allow { localhost; } keys { rndckey; };
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: netfilter is the linux firewall, you can check if anything is blocking with "iptables -L" Looking at your netstat output your bind daemon is indeed listening on the normal ip. i suggest checking out the firewall.

Comment: Thank you a lot! After stopping iptables service it started to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something listening on UDP port 53 of 192.168.2.2. Check that you are allowing access to it via your firewall.

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -n | grep 53
```

or
    iptables -L RH-Firewall-1 -v -n | grep 53

Will produce output similar to this

```
 138K   15M ACCEPT   udp  --  *    *     0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0       udp dpt:53
  265 13572 ACCEPT   tcp  --  *    *     0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:53
```

if you are allowing connections. If you are not allowing connections you can do so with

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

If this works then save your configuration with

```
service iptables save
```

Which will write the current state to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` whic is what is loaded when iptables starts.

Answer (score 1):

netfilter is the linux firewall, you can check if anything is blocking with "iptables -L" Looking at your netstat output your bind daemon is indeed listening on the normal ip. i suggest checking out the firewall.

Comment: Cant believe the first correct answer gets downvoted :-(